# inserting comma separated values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck with the following problem :

I have table 'questions'(question_id,answer) which has 2 columns both are varchar.

The input values are like ('1,2,3' , 'one,two,three')
I need insert query for this and I wish the values should be inserted as :

```
1 one 
2 two
3 three
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you show us your query ?

Comment: Please be more descriptive with the table structure, the query you used, and what exactly you need help with.  You're more likely to get useful help when you've already tried to solve the problem yourself first

Comment: Why are you inserting comma separated values in MySQL and not rows?

Comment: Please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Then please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as per SQl Server

```
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(50)= '1,2,3', 
@Answer VARCHAR(50)= 'i,know,you',
 @a VARCHAR(50), 
 @b VARCHAR(50);

WHILE LEN(@id) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @a = LEFT(@id, CHARINDEX(',', @id+',')-1);
        SET @b = LEFT(@Answer, CHARINDEX(',', @Answer+',')-1);

        INSERT INTO #temp
        VALUES
        (@a,
         @b
        );

        SET @id = STUFF(@id, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @id+','), '');
        SET @Answer = STUFF(@Answer, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @Answer+','), '');
    END;
SELECT *
FROM #temp;
DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Comment: Can you explain the same in MySQL terms?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO questions (question_id,answer) VALUES ('1', 'one');
INSERT INTO questions (question_id,answer) VALUES ('2', 'two');
INSERT INTO questions (question_id,answer) VALUES ('3', 'three');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @var1 = '1,2,3' ;
SET @var2 = 'one,two,three' ; 

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp1; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , Question_Id int );

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp2( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY , Answer VARCHAR(10) );
SET @SQL1 = CONCAT("insert into temp1 (Question_Id) values ('", REPLACE(( @var1 ), ",", "'),('"),"'); " );
SET @SQL2 =  CONCAT("insert into temp2 (Answer) values ('", REPLACE(( @var2), ",", "'),('"),"'); ");

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @SQL1;
EXECUTE stmt1;

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @SQL2;
EXECUTE stmt1;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

select Question_Id, Answer FROM temp1 inner join temp2 on temp1.id = temp2.id
```